# Passing parameters to the fit method of underlying classifiers via StackingCVClassifier in mlxtend package

Tags: python, mlxtend

I'm using `StackingCVClassifier` (from the `mlxtend` package) in Python and one of my classifiers is an `XGBoostClassifier` instance and I'm trying to pass a parameter (early_stopping_rounds or simply verbose) to its fit method via the fit method of the `StackingCVClassifier` object. The fit method does not seem to support this. The fit_transform method has a fit_params argument. But when I pass my parameter (e.g. `**{'XGB_clf__early_stopping_rounds': 20}`) it throw the following error:

> fit() got an unexpected keyword argument 'XGB_clf__early_stopping_rounds.

Is this not supported? Or did I miss something?

Here is a sketch of what I'm trying to do:

```
XGB_clf = XGBClassifier()
other_clf = LogisticRegression()
stacked_clf = StackingCVClassifier(classifiers = [XGB_clf, other_clf], meta_classifier = LogisticRegression(), cv=2)
# trying to pass early_stopping_rounds to XGB_clf.fit
stacked_clf.fit(X_train, y_train, **{XGB_clf__early_stopping_rounds = 50})
```

Answer (score 0):

The developer of `mlxtend` indicated (link below) that, as of September 2018, this is not yet possible.

https://github.com/rasbt/mlxtend/issues/434